Make System.Text.Json's Source Generation feature dynamic
Is there a way to make the process of registering types to serialise dynamic, i.e. not having to tediously write [JsonSerializable(typeof(<type goes here>))] for each type.
So far, I've tried to get all types from the desired assemblies (and their property types by recursive descent) and add the JsonSerializable attribute for each type at runtime using TypeDescriptors. Since soure generation happens at compile time this obviously did not work (duh).
After googling to no real end I opted for my last resort which was implementing a custom IIncrementalGenerator that basically generates a partial class that derives the JsonSerializerContext and adds all required JsonSerializable attributes on top of it.
Now that I have a minimally working generator I get an error that my context class doesn't implement some members -- the same error that occurs when the sources have not yet been generated by the JsonSourceGenerator.
Is there a way to run my generator before the one from System.Text.Json or did anybodoy come up with another way to achieve what I'm trying to implement (the hard way) here?

Currently it is not possible to chain IIncrementalGenerator source generators in a single project, see Is it possible to chain source generators in .net? and (specifically for System.Text.Json) Why does JsonSerializerContext generate empty JSON for a model containing [ObservableProperty] properties? and Allow for a way to ensure some source generators run before / after others #57239.

How many root DTOs are there in the project? Why is it such a problem to use the JsonSerializable attribute for the root DTOs? If there are multiple libraries or big namespaces in a solution, you can create a separate context for each and combine them

The suggested workaround is to chain projects instead, and run the dependent source generator in a dependent project.  But honestly I can't see how that workaround could be used in this case.

@PanagiotisKanavos The core idea is that we don't have to maintain the JSON context manually whenever a class is added to one of our entity projects. The generator should -- ideally -- read a configuration file where I can define each context to be created (and its name) along with the project names from which the types should be added.

@PanagiotisKanavos We have a lot of root types. The main point to take away here is convinience: If the generator automatically creates contexts and adds the desired types as specified per configuration, this no longer needs to be maintained manually and does not have be versioned. I'm not arguing that a .json file is better  than a .cs file in this use case. My task is to make this dynamic and that's what I'm simply trying to achieve.

@dbc So you mean referencing my generator in project A. Then project B (where the JsonSourceGenerator does its work) project A is referenced? Will the JsonSourceGenerator then be able to see my generated contexts?

@devcayed - no, I merely meant that, in a general sense, you can chain source generators only by chaining projects.  E.g. if your classes have [ObservableProperty] source-generated properties you need to implement your JSON source generator contexts in a dependent project. But I don't really see how that could help here which is why I didn't add an answer.  ... Maybe you could create a source generator that defines some type with properties for all your serializable types in one project, then in a dependent project reference that type in a JSON source generator context?

@dbc Ah I see. To be honest I don't think that this will fit into the use case as. This was more of a pilot project to see whether this works dynamically at all and would've been used in our other solutions as a NuGet package so creating two projects kind of misses the idea.

In general my observation is that JSON source generators become brutally difficult to use once you get outside MSFT's expected use case, which seems to be a rest API returning a few simple DTOs.  (System.Text.Json was originally brutal to use back in .NET Core 3.1, the source generator technology seems to be following the same arc.)  That being said I believe you can include multiple projects in a single nuget, see Creating one NuGet package from multiple projects in one solution.

What dbc said +1 but I disagree the generator is limited. It's meant for a specific scenario, it's not a template engine. It can handle complex DTOs in a specific project/library, so the library can be used with AOT compilation. I only have to add [JsonSerializable(typeof(Order))] for record Order(int Id,List<OrderItem> Items, Customer customer)  to get serialization support for the related Customer, OrderItem and Product classes. That's why I ask why can't the projects register their root DTOs. It's the project's/library's job to make itself suitable for AOT compilation

On top of that, using JsonSerializable is one technique that can be used to identify which DTOs need source generation. It's fast because it only scans one type.  If it's not suitable, how will the DTOs be found? Name pattern? Marker interface? Attribute on the DTO (which is no different than an attribute on the context) ? The generator is open source and the Emitter class doesn't have to change. The Parser is the one that identifies DTOs by attribute.

Perhaps, if the scenario is so open-ended and needs an expensive search for multiple types across multiple projects, it would be better to use a code generator based on a template engine like Scriban that generates the same code as JsonSourceGenerator, but can be run only when needed, as part of a build script.

The idea includes gathering types across multiple projects, i.e. the generator theoretically consumes a configuration that looks something like [ { "Context1": [ "Assembly1", "Assembly2" ] } and then collects all types in the given assemblies, creates a context class with name Context1 and then adds all types found as attributes on top of it.

@PanagiotisKanavos As far as I know we don't even intend to use AOT. It's about using JSON Source Generation for all our services. Since changing this for each and every ASP.NET Core project is rather tedious, the idea was to create such a generator that can be packages as a NuGet package so I only have this package to the services and done. No need to write nor maintain these contexts manually.

Additionally, as per requirement the projects which hold all the entities must not have any dependencies on NuGet packages. This means I can't use System.Text.Json in said projects.
